Firebase Realtime Database Secure Rules for a Static Website
I have a personal website based on GitHub pages. Some of its pages need to read data from a Firebase realtime database I created on my own and display the data through HTML.
For the secure rules of the database, my first plan was to allow write permission only for me as owner, and allow read permission for everyone (all the data is visible to public on my website anyways), so I wrote the rules as follows:
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}

However, I keep getting warned that these rules are insecure. I've read the docs but I still have no idea how to write an acceptable ruleset suitable for my case.
It's not necessary that everyone should be permitted to read the database - it's also an option for me if only my website would have access to the database (AND while testing it with localhost). Even though all the data is supposed to be public. But I don't know how to do that either.
Anyone could help?

Are you using Firebase Authentication to sign in the users so you know who they are?  If not, then your security rules will not be able to know anything about who is accessing the site and will not be able to allow or deny access on a per-user basis.  Per-user security with Firebase Authentication is discussed in the documentation.  If you aren't using Firebase Auth, then you really don't have a choice other than to allow all users the same access to your data.

@DougStevenson No, there isn't anything like a user login system on my website and I don't use Firebase Auth. So maybe it's just fine to leave the rules like that (read: true; write: false) and simply disable the warnings? As stated in the question description, the data of my database is intended to be exposed to public anyways, so logically these rules should be actually secure. I was not sure because I've never seen anyone else using such rules on the internet.

It's fine if you don't mind anyone with an internet connection to fully and completely read all of the data in your database.

Or worse , a ro'bit doing it.

As you've said in comments, you're not using Firebase Authentication, which is the only way that security rules can be used to limit per-user access to Realtime Database. This is inherently problematic unless you don't mind anyone with an internet connection to read your entire database with a single request.

Hopefully the passwords are encrypted in there ..

Thanks for pointing this out. I also made some more research on the internet and realized the same thing. Besides, even using Firebase Auth might be problematic in my case because GitHub Pages only provides a static front-end setup. That means if there needs to be an encryption progress it must be implemented in the front-end, which is visible to every visitor, and the attacker can simply simulate the requests. So maybe using any such kind of security authentication is pointless with Github Pages.

I might consider switching to an alternative to Firebase. Beside security issues it has way too many advanced features that I don't need for my website at all. For example my website doesn't require a login system. Also see this answer. The reason why I didn't simply create some JSON files into my repo is the data is being updated relatively often and I don't want every single minor change like that to cause a commit. But anyways, THIS specific topic is cleared now.

Any alternative that lets you query the database directly from your web client is going to have exactly the same issues.  Unless there is a login system in use, and the database understands those logins and gives you a way to express who can read and write what, you won't be able to protect anything at all on a per-user basis.  This is the whole reason why Firebase security rules exist - to avoid having to write backend endpoints that performs the same checks.

Yes I'm thinking about a non-database alternative that fits a purely static website like in my case. Simply using some JSON files is actually good enough regarding the disadvantage that it might cause a lot of commits.
